# How to open Minecraft character skin in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, minecraft

I have a Minecraft skin of a Lion and I want to edit it, here it is:

[image]

When I add this image in UIImageView, it display same, it is not showing the lion character.

It has size of 64*64

So how can we display Minecraft images inside our app?

Comment: Minecraft was designed in 3D space. UIImageView is 2D. That is why.

Comment: @GeneCode so how can we display 3d image ? Do I need UNITY or something ?

Comment: You may want to look into Metal for 3d stuff but it's a lot more complex then you might think right now. https://realm.io/news/3d-graphics-metal-swift/

Answer (score 4):

That image is called a "texture".

That texture is mapped onto 3d model of a lion resulting a "lion character"

In other word, your "lion character" = texture + 3D model of a lion.

Every character skin you're using xcode to open is just the "texture image" as mentioned by @GeneCode

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a renderer. You can create your own one, or use an existing open-source solution (many can be found on GitHub). I understand that is fairly vague, but as mentioned by @JackyW, the Minecraft "texture" is fairly useless without something to render onto. Rendering is the process of converting images or other byte-data into a usable output; in this case a character.

What you need to do is first decide on a structure, as Minecraft textures are literally just 64x64 images. If you "render" this image as-is onto an xcode display (which is what you're doing by loading the image from an asset) you'll get the texture's PNG as-is; that is, 64x64 garbage.

Take a look at this:
https://github.com/games647/Minecraft-Skin-Renderer

Although it's written in PHP, the same concepts apply - build a parser and render the output.

Best of luck!